# SVG element not receiving onclick in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I am writing a javascript application for Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (and maybe other versions eventually). I am trying to make SVG elements that are clickable. I.e., their `onclick` methods should be called when they are clicked.

Here is my first attempt:

```html
<html><body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
<script>

let svg  = document.getElementById("svg");

function clear()
{
    svg.innerHTML = '';
}

function circle(p, r)
{
    let e = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
    e.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
    e.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
    e.setAttribute('r', r);
    svg.appendChild(e);
    return e;
}


onresize = function()
{
    clear();
    let r = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    c1 = circle({x: r.x + r.width/2, y:r.y + r.height - 20}, 10);
    c2 = circle({x: r.x + r.width/2, y:20}, 10);
    c1.onclick = function(){svg.removeChild(c1);}
    c2.onclick = function(){svg.removeChild(c2);}
}
onresize();

</script>
</body></html>
```

This code creates one circle at the top of the page, and one at the bottom. The circles are also recalculated when the page resizes, so that they are always visible. As a test, I want to delete the circle when it is clicked.

Sometimes the above code works. However, when I run it full screen, after opening developer tools at the bottom of the window, and then closing the developer tools, then the bottom circle cannot be clicked -- until after the next time I either zoom or resize the window.

I thought maybe it was a browser bug because it shows up when I use developer tools as described above, and does not occur at all in Firefox. However then I noticed that other websites do not have this problem. Besides it can't be that easy to find a browser bug, as so many sites work in Chrome.

Does anyone see a problem with my Javascript code that could be making the bottom circle fail to receive `onclick` events?

**update**

I cannot reproduce this problem in Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 Linux or Windows. It may be specific to Linux chrome Version 66.0.3359.139.

However, that still doesn't mean it's a browser bug... should the code work or not?

**update**

The problem is also reproducible in Linux Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181. I am having difficulty downgrading to 66.0.3359.139 (I can't find the deb. Google can be annoying that way). So I am now targeting 66.0.3359.181.

**update**

The present problem seems to be caused by

```
<body style="margin:0">
```

If that style is removed, then the present problem does not occur, but [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310990/make-an-svg-fill-the-entire-page-exactly) occurs. The present problem occurs equally with:

```
<style>
html, body, * { 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 0; 
}
</style>
```

This is the case both in my version and the D3 version posted by Dataminion.

So we really have a lump under the rug here... we can step on it but it causes a lump somewhere else. Solve the events, but then SVG can't fill the page. Solve both of the above, but upgrade browser (and deal with a new set of bugs).

**update**

It works with

```
<body style="margin:1">
```

with the only drawbacks being the svg is 1 pixel off, and there is an unwanted scrollbar. Note that:

```
<body style="margin:1;overflow:hidden">
```

removes the scrollbar and reintroduces the bug.

So either `overflow:hidden` or `margin:0` causes the problem. Either of these removes the scrollbar. So the problem is related to there not being a scrollbar (regardless of how it is removed).

Comment: Yes that should work, and yes it **was** probably a browser bug. Not sure what you are expecting from us. Why do you target specifically this outdated Chrome version? If you really need this, then does `c1.addEventListener('click', fn)` also reproduces this bug?

Comment: @Kaiido No, the behavior is the same when using `addEventListener`. Re: why target old chrome: because I upgrade software at my own pace (I have better things to work on than fixing bleeding-edge browser regressions). Since this is an older browser version, it is more likely that workarounds to bugs would be already known.

Comment: Not when the fix is "upgrade to the newer version".

Comment: What happens when you set up an event delegation? i.e `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if(e.target === c1 || e.target === c2) { svg.removeChild(e.target) })`

Comment: @kaiido Re: event delegation... Still had the same issue. BUT, you're on to something here... the delegator was called... with the right coordinates. But `e.target` was set to `body` when I expected `circle`. So one could imagine a workaround where we write our own hit-test logic...

Comment: @kaiido. OK, fine, the consensus seems to be that Chrome 66 is buggy and I should use Chrome 74 or Edge or Firefox instead. They won't have bugs for sure! (Actually, maybe Chrome 66 is fine for 99% of users, who won't open the developer tools... I can develop on something else. That's an answer I would accept)

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you try a parent div for that svg element? It should work.

Cheer,

Comment: `<div><svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg></div>` didn't solve it in chrome 66.0.3359.181.

Comment: Use id inside the div, not the svg please.

Comment: With `<div id="svg">` it doesn't work because the `<circle>` elements do nothing in a `<div>`, only in an `<svg>`.

Answer (score 0):

@kaiido is correct the issue here is browser related as the original code posted functions as expected in modern browsers.

Suggest OP look at [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg) do identify what their current browser supports when it comes to svg

---

Leaving my incorrect(for this question) and ultimately unnecessary d3.js example here as proof that I am willing to admit it when I am wrong and totally misread a question.

```
let myCircles = [
   { "x_axis": 30, "y_axis": 30, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
   { "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple"},
   { "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color" : "red"}];



function onresize()
{
    clear();
   let circles = d3.select("svg")
     .selectAll("circle")
     .data(myCircles).enter()
     .append("circle");

   let attributes = circles
     .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
     .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
     .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
     .attr("id", function(d, i){ return 'c' + i; })  
     .attr('onclick',function(d, i){ return 'c' + i; })   
     .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });  
}

onresize()
```

---

Edit for clarity

It could be said that this is a duplicate of [D3: How delete shape on click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355451/d3-how-delete-shape-on-click-event)

However I would argue that the upvoted answer iterates the item name in a non d3 canonical way.

A callback in an attribute is the where the first input is the "data" and the second is the positional index is more faithful to the design of d3 than to use an externally declared variable to set it. 
.attr('onclick',function(d, i){ return 'c' + i; })

Comment: What makes you think they are using d3? It's all plain vanilla in their snippet/

Comment: you know what... you are totally right. I guess I would say enthusiastically

**Use d3 its designed to make issues just like this super easy to solve!!!**

Comment: A 243KB lib to do just what they could do in plain vanilla for the same number of lines they have to write? Not much a good idea in my mind. What they did should have worked. That's a browser bug it didn't. A lib won't change this.

Comment: @kaiido I agree that if this is going to be their only SVG manipulation d3 is probably overkill.

Comment: @kaiido I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz31047u/) and you are correct it does work out of the box. I tested OPs original code in chrome and it works perfectly I changed the declaration of a function in this fiddle just incase OP is experiencing a closure issue in their browser.

Comment: @Dataminion. With your change (from `onresize = function()` to `function onresize()`) it does not update the shapes on resize, so they do not relocate to where the developer tools were, so I can't tell if it works.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to work. The question is why... any guesses, or do we need to dig through 243KB?

Comment: @personal_cloud They are setting the `onclick` attribute in their answer, which is different than the `.onclick` IDL. Weird it works in your buggy UA, but beware this means you must have the function accessible globally.

Comment: @kaiido Re: `onclick` attribute vs. `.onclick`. I tried it both ways, both of them have the bug in my code. So it must be something D3 is doing...

Comment: D3 was interesting to learn about, but obscures the underlying problem. Note that if you add back the `<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">` to your solution, the bug reappears. (Without that tag, there is a more serious problem, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310990/).

Comment: @personal_cloud So I deleted my original answer because someone pointed out that what you posted is vanilla js if you are actually using d3 then the structure you used isn’t canonical and I can put back in my original d3 recommendation